# Celery resume consuming from a queue

Tags: python, python-2.7, redis, celery, worker

I have different celery queues and at a certain point I want workers to stop consuming from my queues

```
celery_app.control.cancel_consumer(consumer_queue)
```

In a while I want to be able to resume consumers and I do that with the next command

```
celery.control.add_consumer(
    consumer_queue,
    routing_key=consumer_queue,
    destination=['worker-name'],
)
```

At this point I expect `worker-name` will be fetching tasks from `consumer_queue` which my custom router redirects by a `routing_key`. But instead I have this output from a celery inspect

```
celery.control.inspect().active_queues()
```

`{'celery@worker-name': []}`

Some details
Celery: `celery==3.1.23`
Kombu: `kombu==3.0.35`
billiard: `billiard==3.3.0.23`

**Note**: adding consumer via celery flower (`flower==0.8.4`) works even that the command is the same.

What am I doing wrong and how to reenable consuming in a proper way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, it was a premature question with a plain solution: I have provided wrong name for the worker, instead of setting `worker-name` I should provide `celery@worker-name` identifier.
For debug purposes it's also useful to set `reply=True` argument

```
response = celery.control.add_consumer(
    consumer_queue,
    routing_key=consumer_queue,
    destination=['celery@{}'.format(consumer)],
    reply=True,
)
print(response)
```

and you'll see whether operation was successful or not
`[{u'celery@worker-name': {u'ok': u'add consumer consumer-queue'}}]`